# Java unreachable code error to do with object initialisation

Tags: java

So I am getting an error in eclipse (Unreachable code). I think it may be because I am calling an objects method inside a while loop. However I need to declare it during the while loop as the users input has to meet some requirements.

Here is the segment of code from the main method:

```
    double startMoney = 0;
    AccountBasic PrimaryAccount = new AccountBasic(startMoney);


        System.out.println("How much £ would you like to begin with in the format of £0000.00?");
        startMoney = input.nextDouble();

        while (true) {
        PrimaryAccount.deposit(startMoney);
        }


    System.out.println("Your available balance is £" + PrimaryAccount.getBalance()); //unreachable code
```

Here is the code from the objects class:

```
public class AccountBasic extends StockAccount
{

public AccountBasic(double initialBalance)
{
    super(initialBalance);
}

public void withdraw(double amount)
{
    balance -= amount;
}

public void deposit(double amount)
{
    while (true)
    {
    if (amount > 500)
    {
        System.out.println("Please deposit an amount between £1 - £500");
        continue;
    }

    else if (amount <= 500)
    {
        balance += amount;
        break;
    }
    }
}

public double getBalance()
{
    return balance;
}
}
```

Comment: Everything after `while (true) { PrimaryAccount.deposit(startMoney); }` is unreachable in your `main`. Your loop never ends.

Comment: How do you expect your programm to ever get out of `while (true)`?

Answer (score 1):

The code is unreachable because you have a while loop that will run indefinitely, into the end of time. a while loop that runs while true is equal to true. Try changing the while loop so that it ends or get rid of it totally.

Comment: I basically need that code to continue running if the user inputs a number above 500. Once they input a number below 500, the loop stops and
 System.out.println("Your available balance is £" + PrimaryAccount.getBalance());
that statement runs.

Comment: Just get rid of the while loop and it should still work. The reason is because you have another while loop in the deposit() method and you break out of that one but not the while loop in the first code

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an unreachable code error due to this block of code:

```
while (true) {
    PrimaryAccount.deposit(startMoney);
}
```

This loop will always evaluate to true (obviously) and therefore run forever, as you provided no means of breaking out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop will never stops.[Infinite Loop]

```
    while (true) {
          PrimaryAccount.deposit(startMoney);
    }
```

Make it stop by updating condition or using break statement

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop

```
while(true)//Condition is always true
```

So, there is no way to exit that loop, so code after that loop will never execute.
Provide way to exit loop either `break` or change condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may return a Boolean of the method "deposit", remove the while true from there and return if the deposit is correct. Like that:

```
    public boolean deposit(double amount)
    {
        if (amount > 500) {
            System.out.println("Please deposit an amount between £1 - £500");
            return false;
        }
        else if (amount <= 500) {
            balance += amount;
            return true
        }            
    }
```

And then you can make you loop asking for an input like that:

```
while (true) {
        startMoney = input.nextDouble();
        if (PrimaryAccount.deposit(startMoney)) {
            break;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

PS: usually we use the camel case naming convention so your variable "PrimaryAccount" will be better named like that:

```
AccountBasic primaryAccount = new AccountBasic(startMoney);
```